# Set up MS cluster 2016 with multi forest domain

Tags: windows-server-2016, failovercluster, windows-cluster

i am trying to set up a two node MS cluster 2016 with cross forest. currently i am having two separate domains and having trust between domains. like a.com and b.com domains and trust enabled between them. One server is in a.com and another server is in b.com, i want to enable a MS cluster between them. i know we can do Domain-Detached Cluster setup using local accounts.  is there any way using with domain account to setup this cluster between the forest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deploy Multi-domain Cluster (Domain-independent cluster). The major thing is to configure DNS-suffix.

Domain-independent cluster cannot be created without using local Administartor account.

For more detail follow the link:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Failover-Clustering/Workgroup-and-Multi-domain-clusters-in-Windows-Server-2016/ba-p/372059